# Making GET request in yii2 app

Tags: php, yii2

I want to make GET request for some API and get data from it. How can I send get request,get data from JSON and handle that for data that I can input in my HTML? I cant find any tutorial or something, please give some code. For example I want to get data from this API:
https://api.privatbank.ua/p24api/pubinfo?exchange&json&coursid=11

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-httpclient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please reference Yii2 Http Client https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-httpclient